# Change label Posts to Articles in Wordpress

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theming

I'm working on wordpress. Can anybody help me how can I change admin panel menu label in wordpress.

Specifically, I want to change the label for Posts to Articles. And all of the instances in admin panel of Posts to Article.

Kindly advise.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing Admin Menu Labels](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/q/9211)

Answer (score 22, accepted):

Here is the code you need to add into your theme functions file.

```
// Replace Posts label as Articles in Admin Panel 

function change_post_menu_label() {
    global $menu;
    global $submenu;
    $menu[5][0] = 'Articles';
    $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'Articles';
    $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add Articles';
    echo '';
}
function change_post_object_label() {
        global $wp_post_types;
        $labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;
        $labels->name = 'Articles';
        $labels->singular_name = 'Article';
        $labels->add_new = 'Add Article';
        $labels->add_new_item = 'Add Article';
        $labels->edit_item = 'Edit Article';
        $labels->new_item = 'Article';
        $labels->view_item = 'View Article';
        $labels->search_items = 'Search Articles';
        $labels->not_found = 'No Articles found';
        $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No Articles found in Trash';
        $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Add Article';'
}
add_action( 'init', 'change_post_object_label' );
add_action( 'admin_menu', 'change_post_menu_label' );
```

Adapted from: https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/9211/changing-admin-menu-labels

Comment: You may also need to change $wp_post_types['post']->label (string)

Answer (score 11):

I was able to solve this using the `post_type_labels_{$post_type}` filter like so

```
add_filter( 'post_type_labels_post', 'change_post_labels' );

function change_post_labels( $args ) {
        foreach( $args as $key => $label ){
            if( null === $label ) {
                continue;
            }
            $args->{$key} = str_replace( [ __( 'Posts' ), __( 'Post' ) ], __( 'News' ), $label );
        }

        return $args;
}
```

This answer also leaves translation support intact.

The only note is you will  have to add the filter before the `init` action fires.

Comment: I was able to use this filter in my theme functions.php file no problem.

Comment: This is maybe the best answer since you just need one filter that changes all the post's labels at once.
Last thing about the filter priority, it's fine to declare it in the theme's function or even a plugin or mu-plugin, since it will be executed at the right time if registered at or before init.

Answer (score 4):

In your theme functions file include these lines:

```
//Change Posts labels in sidebar admin menu
  function custom_post_menu_label() {
     global $menu;
     global $submenu;
     $menu[5][0] = 'News';
     $submenu['edit.php'][5][0] = 'News';
     $submenu['edit.php'][10][0] = 'Add News';         
  }

 //Change Posts labels in other admin area
  function custom_post_object_label() {
    global $wp_post_types;
    $labels = &$wp_post_types['post']->labels;
    $labels->name = 'News';
    $labels->singular_name = 'News';
    $labels->add_new = 'Add News';
    $labels->add_new_item = 'Add News';
    $labels->edit_item = 'Edit News';
    $labels->new_item = 'News';
    $labels->view_item = 'View News';
    $labels->search_items = 'Search News';
    $labels->not_found = 'No results on News';
    $labels->not_found_in_trash = 'No News in Trash';
    $labels->name_admin_bar = 'Add News';       

   }

 add_action( 'init', 'custom_post_object_label' );
 add_action( 'admin_menu', 'custom_post_menu_label' );
```

Author of previous answer forgot to include '$labels->name_admin_bar = 'Add News';' string.